# Server/Client build using maven/jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, client-server, pom.xml

I'm asking for recommendation on how to configure our Client/Server build. we have a client server architecture. the versions of the Client and the Server are tightly coupled, meaning,

1. they are both stored in the same git repository.
2. during development, changes in Client and the Server must be made at the same time to maintain compatibility in some cases
3. the Client code is dependant on server code

at the moment they do not share a parent pom.
I'm wondering what would be the best way to have both Client and Server compiled from the same branch. keeping in mind branches are created all the time and developers may run a job on a private branch using parameterized builds.

options:

1. Create combined parent pom.
2. Create a Jenkins job and execute 2 maven builds one of the other using shell commands
3. Add branch name to the version and deploy the server to the Artifactory

Answer (score 0):

### Maven modules

You can use *modules* to [aggregate](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation_or_Multi-Module) both the client and server projects within the same Maven build. You don't have to have a *parent* POM in the inheritance sense, but you need one more POM to aggregate the two projects. You'll need the following directory/files structure (normally all POM files are named `pom.xml`, I renamed them here for clarity):

```
main-pom.xml
server/
  server-pom.xml
client/
  client-pom.xml
```

In `main-pom.xml` specify the projects to be built in the "modules" section:

```
<modules>
  <module>server</module>
  <module>client</module>
</modules>
```

The module names have to be the directory names. Don't worry about the order, Maven will figure it out according to dependencies.

You can combine this approach with [*inheritance*](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) (the real parent POM) if it makes sense to share properties between your client and server projects (version, common dependencies, plugins, etc.).

Comment: Some people raised a concern that since the two are separate executables they shouldn't be in the same pom, any thoughts about that?

Comment: As long as each has its own POM, they are built separately and still produce their own artifacts. Aggregation won't change that, it just groups the two builds.

Comment: @user3722667 Did you get a chance to try modules?